# Bootstrap css in a table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a table in HTML that represents editable content, and then use Bootstrap components/CSS to style it.

One column contains different components based on the content. In the simplest case, it is a single component, like a input text area.

In other cases, it may be a collection of different components. I'm having difficulty keeping two or more Bootstrap components oriented horizontally instead of stacked in the cell.

Here's a JSFiddle of what I'm trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/mjeffw/tc10mka9/4/. (Make sure your browser window is set to 768 pixel width or greater.)

The top of the JSFiddle shows the same list of components in an inline form. Notice in the second line how the 'spinner' text input field is on the same line as the select component ('Broad').

In the table below this, you see the same components but the select and the spinner text input are stacked.

Is there a way to coerce the two component to be horizontally arranged instead of vertically stacked?

I know I could embed another table inside this column, but would like to see if there is a simpler approach.

Here's the HTML that is in that cell:

```
        <td>
            <div class='form-group'>
                <select class="form-control input-sm">
                    <option value="Broad">Broad</option>
                    <option value="Moderate">Moderate</option>
                    <option value="Single">Single</option>
                </select>
                <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                    <span class="input-group-btn"> 
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"> <i class="fa fa-minus"></i> </button>
                    </span> 
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" value="+0" style="text-align: right; min-width: 4em;" /> 
                    <span class="input-group-btn"> 
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> </button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
```